# bash shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, users, scripts

How do I write a bash shell script that requests the user's name, verify that it exists and, if it does, show the following information:

```
Username: xxxx
User ID: xxxx
Group ID: xxxx
Shell: / bin / xxx
Directory: / home / xxx
```

I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese el nombre del usuario"
read nombreUsuario
id $nombreUsuario

RESULTADO="$?"

if [ $RESULTADO = "0" ];then
    id $nombreUsuario | tee salida.txt
    echo "id del usuario:"
    cut -f 1-1 -d" "--output-delimiter="; " salida.txt
    #asignar la salida de cut a una variable
    UID=$(cut -f 1-1 -d" " --output-delimiter="; " salida.txt)
    clear
    echo "ID del Usuario: $UID"

    #quitar el texto UID
    UIDUNICO=$(echo UID | cut -d= -f2)
    echo "ID del Usuario: $UIDUNICO"
fi
```

But that just shows the first part. How do I show the rest?

Comment: That's what the `finger` and `id` commands are for.

Comment: Don't use uppercase variable names for internal purposes. You risk overriding special shell variables and environment variables. And that just happened in your script there. `UID` is a special, read-only, shell variable that holds your uid. Any attempt to assign anything to `UID` will fail.

Comment: This can be done with awk in like couple of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get the gid, uid, shell and directory:

```
printf "Enter username: "
read user

groupid=$( id -g $user )
userid=$( id -u $user ) 
usershell=$( grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $7 }' ) 
userdirectory=$( grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $6 }' )
```

Comment: Enclose search term inside backslash and feed the file to awk directly instead of piping from grep

Comment: why at copy in the archive in nano  appears syntax error?

Comment: That's strange, what version of bash are you using? (do this command -> "bash --version | head -1"). Also try to type in it manullay instead of copying, there becomes often problems when you copy and paste the code from a website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `python` solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(sys.argv[1] + ':'):
            parts = line.rstrip().split(':')
            print 'Username: ' + parts[0] + '\n' + 'User ID: ' + parts[2].rstrip()
            print 'Group ID: ' + parts[3] + '\n' + 'Shell: ' + parts[6].rstrip()
            print 'Directory: ' + parts[5].rstrip()
```

You can put all the `print` statements in a single line, for better view-ability i have put it in several lines. Save this as a file e.g. `username.py`. Run  the script giving the username as the first argument to the script. For example:

```
python username.py foobar
```

where `foobar` is the username.

If found the output will be like:

```
Username: foobar
User ID: 1000
Group ID: 1000
Shell: /bin/bash
Directory: /home/foobar
```

- `line.startswith(sys.argv[1] + ':')` will read each line of the `/etc/passwd` file to check whether it begins with the given username. The `:` will ensure that we don't select e.g. `foobarspam` while our input username is `foobar`
- If so, then `line.split(':')` will make a list of fields (separated by `:`) of the line
- Then we print out the desired indexed values from the list along with the appropriate string.

Answer (score 0):

If with "the user's" name you meant the username of the user running the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Username: " username
if [ "${username}" == "${USER}" ]
then
    user_data="$(< /etc/passwd sudo grep "^${username}:")"
    echo "Username: ${username}"
    echo "User ID: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f3)"
    echo "Group ID: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f4)"
    echo "Shell: $(<<<"${user_data}"  cut -d: -f7)"
    echo "Directory: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f6)"
fi
```

If with "the user's" name you meant any username:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Username: " username
if [ $(< /etc/passwd grep "^$username:") ]
then
    user_data="$(< /etc/passwd sudo grep "^${username}:")"
    echo "Username: ${username}"
    echo "User ID: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f3)"
    echo "Group ID: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f4)"
    echo "Shell: $(<<<"${user_data}"  cut -d: -f7)"
    echo "Directory: $(<<<"${user_data}" cut -d: -f6)"
fi
```

Comment: ok but when i pste this code in nano and execute with sh xxx... sintax error apear

Answer (score 0):

Another bash way:

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "Username: " user

if IFS=: details=($(getent passwd $user))
then 
    printf "Username: %s\nUser ID: %d\nGroup ID: %d\nShell: %s\nDirectory: %s\n" "${details[0]}" "${details[2]}" "${details[3]}" "${details[6]}" "${details[5]}"
fi
```

One can, in a single step

- run a command, taking its output - `$(getent passwd $user)`
- split the output on `:`, save the result as an array  `IFS=: details=(...)`
- and use the exit status of the command for testing in `if`

Then it's just a matter of printing the correct fields.